# "Can" vs "could" vs "would"

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

I have a question regarding the usage of **can, could, would**. I know **can** Is less polite when it is used to request people to do things. I know **would** and **could** also be used in a more polite way. But can I interchange would and could when making requests to people.

Here are some examples:

1a- Helen, **would** you please be quiet? I am trying to concentrate?

1b- Helen, **could** you please be quiet? I am trying to concentrate?

1c- Helen, **can** you please be quiet? I am trying to concentrate? (I know this one is not so polite.)

2a- Hello sir, **can** you please tell me where the bank is?

2b- Hello sir, **could** you please tell me where the bank is?

2c- Hello sir, **would** you please tell me where the bank is?

3a- **Could** you please email me the directions to your house?

3b- **Would** you please email me the directions to your house?

So when making requests in a polite manner can I use **would** and **could** interchangeably in sentences like these ?